# org.apahe.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender and org.apache.log4j.FileAppender can not be resolved while migrating log4j 1.2 to log4j 2.17

Tags: java

While migrating from log4j 1.2 to log4j 2.17, I am unable to resolve FileAppender and JDBCAppender in y codebase.

I tried to replace JDBCAppender with JdbcAppender but it is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The full classnames in log4j 2.x are:

- `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender`
- `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcAppender`

See the [javadocs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/index.html) for more information.

As the package names imply, these are part of the `log4j-core` dependency.

---

> I tried to replace `JDBCAppender` with `JdbcAppender` but it is not allowed.

"It is not allowed" is not the error message that you got.

My guess is that you didn't use the correct package name.  Error messages will give clues as to what you *actually* did wrong.